# How can I use these statement properly?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

```
// Windows CE Fn Keys
alKeys.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.F7));   // "F7" key
alKeys.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.F8));   // "F8" key
alKeys.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.F9));   // "SCAN" key
alKeys.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.F19));  // Gun trigger
```

I'm trying to call a method like this:

```
  if((alKeys.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.F9))==true))
  {
       rfid.SetCallback(new RfidCallbackProc(myRfidCallback));
       //this is the method i am calling

   };   // "SCAN" key
```

But I got this error:

> Error 1   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'        SmartDeviceProject1

So how to do it properly?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: The `.Add` method of `alKeys` returns an int which cannot be compared to bool. You need to tell what type `alKeys` is if you expect more detailed help.

Comment: yes, just like filburt said, you can compared int to bool, maybe what really you want is to check is what user pressed, is that F9 in your case? am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((alKeys.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.F9))==true))
```